# Smoothness of a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^n $

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\exp\left(\frac{-1}{1-|x|^2}\right), &\text{ if } |x| < 1,
\\
0, &\text{ if } |x|\geq  1.
\end{cases}
$$ Prove that $f$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere. ($x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for fixed $n$.)

Well, this is obvious for $|x|>1$ and easy enough for the first derivative at $|x|=1$, but I can't seem to use the definition of the Gateaux derivative to show it for $|x|<1$. Any advice would be appreciated.

(This is not homework.)

Comment: $|x|^2$ is just $x\cdot x$, so for $|x|<1$ the function is just $e^{1/(x\cdot x-1)}$ which is nice and $C^\infty$ by virtue of being composed from such functions. So the only real work you have to do is at $|x|=1$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much.

Comment: If $f$ is smooth then the radially symmetric function $f(r)$ is smooth except perhaps at $r=0$, so your situation reduces to looking at $e^{-1/(1-r^2)}$ when $r=1$. I think the proof at that point involves splitting into left and right limits in the derivative definition, showing what form the derivatives on the left come in and then using the fact that $P(y)e^{-y}\to0$ as $y\to\infty$ regardless of how fast the rational function $P$ grows.

Comment: My comments at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59842 for the one-variable case at the origin might be of help.

Answer (score 3):

We can show by induction that 
$$\partial_{\alpha}f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{P_{\alpha}(x)}{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha|}}\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)&\mbox{ if }|x|<1,\\\
0&\mbox{ otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
where $\alpha\in\mathbb N^n$ and $P_{\alpha}$ is a polynomial. It's true for $\alpha=0$, and if $\alpha=e_k$ and $|x|<1$, 
$$\partial_{e_k}f(x)=-\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)\frac{2x_k}{(|x|^2-1)^2},$$
which shows that $f$ is also differentiable at $|x|=1$ and $P_{e_k}(x)=-2x_k$. If we assume that the property is true for $|\alpha|\leq p$ and $|\alpha|=p+1$ then let $k$ such that $\alpha_k\neq 0$, and put $\alpha'=\alpha-e_k$. Then $|\alpha'|=p$ and for $|x|<1$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\partial_{\alpha}P(x)&=\frac{\partial_{e_k}P_{\alpha'}(x)}{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha'|}}\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)+\frac{P_{\alpha'}(x)(-2|\alpha'|-1)2x_k}{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha'|+1}}\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)\\
&+\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)\frac{P_{\alpha'}(x)}{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha'|}}\frac{2x_k}{(1-|x|^2)^2}\\
&=\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)\frac 1{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha|}}\Big(\partial_{e_k}P_{\alpha'}(x)(1-|x|^2)^2\\
&- 2(1-|x|^2)P_{\alpha'}(x)x_k+2x_kP_{\alpha'}(x)
\Big)\\
&=\exp\left(\frac 1{|x|^2-1}\right)\frac 1{(1-|x|^2)^{2|\alpha|}}\left(\partial_{e_k}P_{\alpha'}(x)(1-|x|^2)^2+2|x|^2x_kP_{\alpha'}(x)\right).
\end{align*}
So we got the induction formula 
$$P_{\alpha'+e_k}(x)=\partial_{e_k}P_{\alpha'}(x)(1-|x|^2)^2+2|x|^2x_kP_{\alpha'}(x),$$
and $\partial_{\alpha}f(x)=0$ if $x=1$.