# infinitely differentiable function-multivariable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let's consider the open ball $B\left ( \omega ,r \right )\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $f(x)$ equal $\exp\left(\frac{1}{\left | x-\omega  \right |^{2}-r^{2}}\right)$ if $x\in B$, and $0$ if $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus
 B$. Prove that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. The idea I had in mind was to find a general formula for the $n$th derivative, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: The problem is on the boundary of the ball, i.e. when $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_k-\omega_k)^2\right)^{1/2}=r$. Consider function $g(t)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{t^2-r^2}\right)$, then $$f(x)=g\left(\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_k-\omega_k)^2\right)^{1/2}\right).$$ Try to prove that $g$ is smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/smoothness-of-a-real-valued-function-on-mathbbrn/92553#92553), it's shown when $\omega=0$ and $r=1$. We define $g(x):=f\left(r(x+\omega)\right)$, and we know that $g$ is smooth. We deduce that so is $f$, as the map $x\mapsto r(x+\omega)$ is smooth and bijective, with smooth inverse (for the composition).