# How $\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x^{-2}}}{x^{r}}=0$ for $r>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to show that $$\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x^{-2}}}{x^{r}}=0$$ for $r\in \mathbb N.$

My attempt: If I apply l'hospital rule then $\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x^{-2}}}{x^{r}}=\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x^{-2}} 2x^{-3}}{rx^{r-1}}$. But it is again $(0/0)$ form...

Motivation: This has a connection to [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)

Comment: $e^{-y}y^{a} \to 0$ as $ y \to \infty$ for any real number $a$.

Comment: thanks. but how to apply this here? can you elaborate

Comment: Take $y=x^{-2}$.

Comment: Related: [Examples of applying L'Hôpitals rule ( correctly ) leading back to the same state?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59842/13130)

Answer (score 1):

If you change variables and let $y = 1/x$ then your limit becomes

$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^r}{e^{y^2}}$$

and L'hospital will work with that more easily.  Since $r$ is a positive integer, you can repeat until $r=0$ or $1$ and then check those cases.