# Why must $n-\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+\lfloor\frac n3\rfloor-\dotsb$ grow like $n\ln2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, divisor-sum

Let
$$a(n):=n-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac n5\right\rfloor-\dotsb.$$
Note that this is a finite sum. Naïvely,
$$a(n)\approx n-\frac n2+\frac n3-\frac n4+\frac n5-\dotsb=n\ln2,$$
and so in particular
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(n)}n=\ln2.\tag{$*$}\end{align}
However, I'm having trouble proving this formally. In particular, the difficulty lies in showing that the error goes to zero.

The OEIS page for this sequence, https://oeis.org/A059851, claims that $(*)$ is correct, but I have been unable to prove it. Can someone find a rigorous proof?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115824/42969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} $ denote the partial sum of the alternating harmonic series. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{a(n)}{n} - S_n
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \frac{n}{k} \right)\frac{1}{n} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \frac{n}{k} \right)\frac{1}{n} - \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2k}\right\rfloor - \frac{n}{2k} \right)\frac{2}{n} \\
&\to \int_{0}^{1} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor - \frac{1}{x} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{1} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor - \frac{1}{x} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Here, we utilized the fact that $x \mapsto \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor - \frac{1}{x}$ (with a suitable modification at $x=0$) is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Ooh! This is very nice and clean

Comment: The question looks like a duplicate to me, compare your previous answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2756297/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20(-1)%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%20n%20k%5Cright%5Crfloor%24)

Comment: @MartinR, Oops, I didn't know I have already answered the same question... my memory seems quite volatile! :s I'll pay more caution next time.