# Prove that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\frac{x}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $x$ be any positive real number, and define a sequence
>   $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by $$ a_n=\frac{[x]+[2x]+\cdots+[nx]}{n^2} $$
>   where $[x]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. Prove
>   that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\frac{x}{2}$.

I'm pretty stuck on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $[kx] = kx - \{kx\}$, where $\{y\}$ denotes the fractional part of $y$.

Comment: Hint: $t-1\lt[t]\leqslant t$ for every $t$. (The hypothesis that $x$ is positive is not needed.)

Comment: @Did haha! Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{ [x] + [2x] + [3x] + \dotsb + [nx] }{n^2} = x/2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41756/how-to-show-lim-n-to-infty-a-n-frac-x-2x-3x-dotsb-nx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you've seen the comments by now but notice
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac{x \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n}{n^2} & < & \frac{[x] + [2x] + \cdots + [nx]}{n^2} & \le & \frac{x \frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n^2} \\
\downarrow && \Downarrow \text{Squeezed} \Downarrow && \downarrow \\
\frac{x}{2} && \frac{x}{2} && \frac{x}{2}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Both $\frac12n(n-1)$ should read $\frac12n(n+1)$.

Comment: @Did oops thanks!

Answer (score 5):

By definition

$$a_n=\frac{x+2x+\ldots+nx-\{x\}-\ldots\{nx\}}{n^2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}x-\frac{\{x\}+\ldots\{nx\}}{n^2}$$

and now just observe that

$$\{x\}+\ldots+\{nx\}\le n$$ and the left hand side is non-negative.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient - I believe you really need to squeeze this from both sides. As of right now you have a lower bound, but not something above.

Comment: Why not sufficient, @DanZimm? The first summand in the right side goes to $\;\frac x2\;$ and the second one is non-negative and less or equal $\;\frac 1n\;$ and thus goes to zero. And you did downvote my answer because "you think" it is not sufficient?

Comment: Because this isn't a full proof, if you're going to be comparing sequences you need to use the squeeze/sandwich theorem which requires both an upper and lower bound.

Comment: @Dan, are you saying that from $\;k_n\ge 0\;$ for all $\;n\;$ and $\;k_n\le\frac1n\;$ , it doesn't follow that $\;k_n\longrightarrow 0\;$ ?? Because this is exactly what I showed above...

Comment: @DanZimm, this is a full proof. It follows since if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = c$ both exist and $a_n = b_n + c_n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists and is equal to $b + c$. In this case, the first limit converges to $x/2$ and the second to $0$.

Comment: @Joel ah right, nonetheless he didn't justify it in this way (hence my confusion). Silly me!

Comment: @DanZimm, I think Tim's proof is completely correct and complete. What isn't clear to you from it? Besides this, to rush to downvote is not a good policy...ever. And many (most?) answers in this site aren't "full" as most members expect the posters to do some part of the job...

Comment: @DonAntonio this is true, I have learned from this post. Thankfully I don't often downvote.

Comment: @Timbuc if you edit your post with something along "and it follows from the linearity of limits" (or just edit it at all) I will change my vote (as of right now I cannot!).

Comment: Ok @DanZimm, thank you.

Comment: @Timbuc i just wanted to apologize for the ruckus I had caused before - I was entirely wrong and out of line.

Comment: @DanZimm, don't worry, please. It happens to us all now and then.